# node.js eventEmitter + http.request

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

i did this tutorial [node.js eventEmitter](http://www.mshiltonj.com/blog/2011/10/04/nodejs-eventemitter-example-with-custom-events/), it worked nicely. I added a method that uses http.request to get data, which works and emit the data.

the problem is that the listener doesn't catch the event !

can someone help ?

code :

```
var events = require('events');
var util = require('util');
var http = require('http');

//http request options, it query the twitter api and get the public timeline, works!
var options = {
    hostname : 'api.twitter.com',
    port : 80,
    method : 'get',
    path : '/1/statuses/public_timeline.json?count=3&include_entities=true'
}

// The Thing That Emits Event
Eventer = function(){
  events.EventEmitter.call(this);

//tutorial examples
  this.kapow = function(){
    var data = "BATMAN"
    this.emit('blamo', data);
  }

//tutorial examples
  this.bam = function(){
     this.emit("boom");
  }

//my method
  this.GetTweetList = function(){
    var tweets = "";
        var req = http.request(options, function(response){
                    var body = "";
                    response.on('data',function(data){
                        body += data;
                    });
                    response.on('end', function(){
                        tweets = JSON.parse(body);
                        this.emit("tweets", tweets);
                        util.puts('!!!!!!!!!! got some data !!!!!!!!!! \n');
                    });
                });
        req.end();
    }
 };
util.inherits(Eventer, events.EventEmitter);

// The thing that listens to, and handles, those events
Listener = function(){

//tutorial examples
this.blamoHandler =  function(data){
    console.log("** blamo event handled");
    console.log(data);
  },

//tutorial examples
  this.boomHandler = function(data){
    console.log("** boom event handled");
  }

//my listener method
  this.GetTweetListHandler = function(data){
        console.log("** tweets event handled");
        util.put(data);
        util.puts('!!!!!!!!!! got some data in listener !!!!!!!!!! \n');

    }

};

// The thing that drives the two.
//instanciating the object and liking the methodes
var eventer = new Eventer();
var listener = new Listener(eventer);
eventer.on('blamo', listener.blamoHandler);
eventer.on('boom', listener.boomHandler);
eventer.on('tweets', listener.GetTweetListHandler);


//calling the methodes
eventer.kapow();//works
eventer.bam();//works
setInterval(eventer.GetTweetList, 2000);
//eventer.GetTweetList();// still waiting but the eventer display that he got the data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard one to spot ...

The problem is the `this` pointer from `this.emit("tweets", tweets);`. You are doing this call from within an anonymous callback passed to `response.on`, so `this` does not represent the `Eventer` object that you created.
To solve it, you need to "save" the `this` pointer (a common practice).

```
var tweets = "";
var self = this;
....
self.emit("tweets", tweets);
```