# Node.js setting 'this' when running a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I'm creating a module in Node.js that has an exported class function constructor.  I added 2 prototyped functions to that class but I also have a bunch of free standing functions.

The plain functions I use as handlers for events and callbacks internally to the class.  I don't want to expose those functions as part of the classes prototype.

In the chaining of the free standing functions I want to reference the main class that the module is built around so I can emit events (I used `util.inherits(myclassconsructor, EventEmitter)`).  But in my inner functions `this` is not correct.  I tried making a global variable to the module called self and did `self = this` as the first line of the constructor.

I then checked that if I did `self.on("message name", function() {console.log("worked")});` that it did indeed work.

Then I went to my main module which constructs the module in question and created the above module and bound to the same event.  I don't receive the event outside the module...

Module A

```
var self;
function A() {
  self = this;
  self.on('message name', function() { console.log('test') }); // Firing
  doStuff();
}
function doStuff() {
  api.callApi(callback);
}
function callback() {
  self.emit('message name');
}
```

Module B

```
var a = new A();
a.on('message name', domystuff);  // Not firing
function domystuff() {
  console.log('my stuff');
}
```

Found this thread which seems to be the issue I'm having but I'm not able to reproduce results. [node.js eventEmitter + http.request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271336/node-js-eventemitter-http-request?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF I understand correctly, you want to use:

```
doStuff.call(this);
```

instead. The the `call` function will call the function it is called upon, and set `this` to the first parameter.

See the documentation at [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

As for your callback issue I might be tempted to restructure you code like this...

```
var inst = this;
api.callApi(function(p1,p2,p3) { inst.emit('message name',p1,p2,p3); });
```

But there are slightly more elegant methods.

Comment: I was wondering how to do that!  I still have a problem doing that though because my callback has the context of the results.  For example my `api.callApi(callback);` is `mysqlConnection.query("select * from tablex", callback);`  I'd give you a +1 but I'm to new...

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete example.  My code is to large to share and without my external servers it would take a lot of effort to mock up the connections I'm working with.  Any suggestions how to share a lot of code?

Comment: JSFiddle is good for sharing code. Voting my answer up would be great, but until you get reputation you can't. You can still accept the answer tho! :-)

Comment: After consulting another pair of eyes I discovered my issue was that I forgot to export my message name.

In my Module B I was doing:
`var module = require('module');
var a = new module.A();
a.on(module.EVENT_NAME, callback);`

Was looking for the hard answer!  It worked in Module A because the EVENT_NAME had context but in Module B it did not because I forgot the exports.EVENT_NAME...

Sorry for wasting anyone's time.  Spent a long time on a simple issue!